# Measure the effectiveness of video advertising that can be divided into some parts

Tags: mathematical-statistics, forecasting, predictive-models, modeling

I would like to measure the effectiveness of video advertising that are of a certain length of time and divided into parts.
For example, suppose there is a video advertisement that can be divided into A, B, and C parts (Each part is 5 minutes), and viewers can start watching at any time and stop at any time. (Many viewers start watching in the middle of a part and end up watching in the middle of another part.)
In this case, a viewer who watched part B for 3 minutes and part C for 2 minutes is quantified as [A,B,C]=[0,3,2].
Is it possible to create a regression model with A, B, and C as explanatory variables and whether or not the purchase was made as the objective variable?
Is there any problem with the above model in the first place, or
If you have a use case for a similar model, I would appreciate it if you could let me know.